# accessing schemas in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm new to postgresql and i'd like to access a table named Paths located in the schemas as shown in this image :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6aTn.jpg

in pgadmin this request works :

```
select * from "Schemas"."Paths"
```

but i can't make it work in php.

i've tried this so far :

```
pg_prepare($connection, "my_query", "Select * from \"Schemas\".\"Paths\"");
pg_execute($connection,"my_query");
```

but it didn't work...

Edit: 
I don't have an error i just get NULL when i try :

```
var_dump(pg_fetch_array(pg_execute($connection,"my_query")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pg_prepare($connection, "my_query", 'Select * from "Schemas"."Paths"');
pg_execute($connection,"my_query");
```

Comment: Well i had tried without the quotes and it didn't work neither in php nor in pgadmin. Note that i don't have an error but the result is null when i try var_dump(pg_fetch_array(pg_execute($connection,"my_query")));

Comment: Ahh ok, i see. It's probably because of the reserve words.

Try this (see edit).

Comment: hum still not working but i can't even retrieve anything from a metatable. I'm switching to java servlet! thanks anyway!